# ImportError: No module named site - Python27 - MacPorts

Tags: python, macports

Ok, I recently installed Python27 with macports, but something happened and I created  a mess. So I uninstalled it with `sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents python27`. Then I reinstalled it, did `sudo port select --set python python27`. All successful up to this point. But now I go to run python, and I get an error:

`ImportError: No module named site`

Any ideas? It's been driving me crazy for the past hour.

Mac OS X Lion / Python 2.7 / MacPorts

Comment: Looks like you don't have django in your path.

Comment: No, it should have nothing to do with it, I think; I will delete the reference to it in my post: Django is no longer installed.

Comment: I have to +1 @jterrace and push for homebrew. macports had always given me headaches with dependencies. homebrew has been a blessing

Comment: @Pedro Werneck: no virtualenv

Comment: @jterrace, jdi: I've heard that homebrew still has problems with breadth of package coverage, but I've also heard that it has its plusses; nevertheless, my question isn't which is better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution for this problem was to make it sure your `PYTHONHOME` environment variable is set correctly. You will receive this error if `PYTHONHOME` is pointing to invalid location or to another Python installation you are trying to run.

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason using %..% syntax isn't working for me so I've hardcoded it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and in the end it turned out to be to do with permissions.

Stupid mac-ports did something, not quite sure what, but I applied `sudo chmod -R a+x $PYTHONPATH` (which basically makes all files beneath `$PYTHONPATH` executable by *everyone*).

It's a nasty, and perhaps dangerous fix from a security perspective, but at this stage I just want to get it to work!